# Convert Java Linked Hashmap with linked Hashmap entries to array of objects

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am using the "retrieve all" object store component and I get back a java payload like this:

```
{
  {
    target: "test-app-387562893"
  }
}
```

which is a LinkedHashMap with the entries.

I need to convert this to an Array of objects i.e.

```
[
  {
    target: "test-app-387562893"
  }
]
```

I have tried using `pluck` to map the entries into an array.

input: [Original LinkedHashMap payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQJDV.png)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload pluck (value,key) -> { 
  (key): value
}
```

output: [Array with LinkedHashMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzqya.png)

However that just adds the entire LinkedHashMap as an item in the array.

Is there another way to get LinkedHashMap entries into objects in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should have looked further into [this area](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-objects) of the DW documentation.

Looks like `dw::core::Objects::entrySet(payload)` will convert it to an array of objects.

Incidentally as soon as I ran the original payload through a Foreach scope (which is why I needed an Array of Objects) to see the error it generated the error message recommended using the `entrySet` function as well. Kudos to the dw and studio engineers for that.